# Kotlin Initialize Variable Inside Function in Constructor

Tags: class, kotlin, init

In Kotlin variables not declared as nullable or lateinit must be initialized in the constructor (or init). I am trying to do this like this:

```
class Foo{
    var foo:myType
    init{
        complicatedFooInit()
    }

    fun complicatedFooInit(){
         foo = //a whole bunch of code here
    }

}
```

I still get the `Property must be initialized or declared abstract` error. You can easily reproduce this by making `myType` an `Int` and just setting it equal to 3 in the `complicatedFooInit` function. Obviously there are ways around this (just not making it a function, having `complicatedFooInit` return `myType` and setting foo equal to it, etc.). My question is, why is the above code invalid? Or is it valid with some tweaking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiler have no idea what's going on inside `complicatedFooInit()` function (cause it may be too burden to investigate all execution flow of potentially dozens nested functions called from `init` block). He wants to see initialization directly inside `init` block. So you need to make `complicatedFooInit()` return desired value:

```kotlin
class Foo {
    var foo: myType

    init {
        foo = complicatedFooInit()
    }

    fun complicatedFooInit(): myType {
        //a whole bunch of code here
       return ...
    }
}
```

Actually, in this case property initialization on declaration site will be more concise (no need for `init` block at all):

```kotlin
var foo: String = complicatedFooInit()
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this workaround, as mentioned. Fair point about the burden allowing this would place on the compiler, though it clearly seems achievable.

Comment: Maybe achievable, but you have to consider that *fast* compile times are a major requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Consider also that you can have multiple `init` blocks, so if you want to extract some part of initialization into a function, e.g.

```
init {
    complicatedFooInit()
    complicatedBarInit()
}
```

I would replace each function by a separate `init` block:

```
// comment about foo initialization
init {
    // body of complicatedFooInit()
}

// comment about bar initialization
init {
    // body of complicatedBarInit()
}
```

The problem is that you can't pass arguments to `init` blocks; but any arguments you'd pass to `complicatedFooInit` can only depend on the primary constructor parameters, and so can be set up in the beginning of the corresponding `init` block.

You also can't call the same function twice with different parameters,

```
init {
    complicatedFooInit(true)
    complicatedFooInit(false)
}
```

but you wouldn't want to anyway, because it would initialize `foo` twice; unless `complicatedFooInit` initializes different variables depending on its arguments, but it would make the compiler's burden mentioned in Михаил Нафталь's answer much worse!

Comment: I believe you can pass arguments to init - the primary constructor parameters, so it is technically possible (though likely bad practice) to call the Init function with two different parameters. I believe the compiler burden is the ultimate reason you can't do what I want.